# Using Stored Procedures in ColdFusion / Lucee

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

This is how I write all my database interactions now in Lucee:

```
storedproc 
    procedure='OrderDetail.WhereOrderHeaderID' {
    procparam value=session.Usr.UsrID;
    procparam value=url.OrderHeaderID;
    procresult resultset=1 name='OrderDetail';
    procresult resultset=2 name='OrderHeader';
}
```

Assuming I've done this in SQL Server:

```
create schema OrderDetail authorization dbo
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'OrderHeader.[get]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROC OrderHeader.[get]
GO
CREATE PROC OrderHeader.[get]
(@UsrID Int
,@OrderHeaderID Int
) AS
SELECT OrderHeaderInfo
FROM OrderHeader
WHERE OrderHeaderID = @OrderHeaderID

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'OrderDetail.WhereOrderHeaderID') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROC OrderDetail.WhereOrderHeaderID
GO
CREATE PROC OrderDetail.WhereOrderHeaderID
(@UsrID Int
,@OrderHeaderID Int
) AS
SELECT Item,Qty
FROM OrderDetail
WHERE OrderHeaderID = @OrderHeaderID
exec OrderHeader.[get] @UsrID,@OrderHeaderID
```

Comment: could you share more of what you are looking for in this review. I can't see anything more than the need for better formatting in your SQL.

Comment: Also, in terms of SQL, consider using `SET NOCOUNT ON / OFF` in your stored procedures. Enabling the setting at the beginning of a procedure, and disabling at the end, suppresses any extraneous '(x) rows affected' messages generated within the procedure. As those messages are normally discarded by CF anyway, suppressing them saves a *bit* of network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

your code could use some formatting so that it can be read without much effort

> ```
> create schema OrderDetail authorization dbo
> IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'OrderHeader.[get]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
> DROP PROC OrderHeader.[get]
> GO
> CREATE PROC OrderHeader.[get]
> (@UsrID Int
> ,@OrderHeaderID Int
> ) AS
> SELECT OrderHeaderInfo
> FROM OrderHeader
> WHERE OrderHeaderID = @OrderHeaderID
>
> IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'OrderDetail.WhereOrderHeaderID') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
> DROP PROC OrderDetail.WhereOrderHeaderID
> GO
> CREATE PROC OrderDetail.WhereOrderHeaderID
> (@UsrID Int
> ,@OrderHeaderID Int
> ) AS
> SELECT Item,Qty
> FROM OrderDetail
> WHERE OrderHeaderID = @OrderHeaderID
> exec OrderHeader.[get] @UsrID,@OrderHeaderID
> ```

you also should be consistent about Capitalization of Keywords in SQL, it will make it easier to see what is going on in your SQL.

```
CREATE SCHEMA OrderDetail authorization dbo
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM sys.objects 
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'OrderHeader.[get]') 
                   AND type IN (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROC OrderHeader.[get]
GO

CREATE PROC OrderHeader.[get]
(
    @UsrID INT
    ,@OrderHeaderID INT
) AS
SELECT OrderHeaderInfo
    FROM OrderHeader
    WHERE OrderHeaderID = @OrderHeaderID

IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM sys.objects 
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'OrderDetail.WhereOrderHeaderID') 
                   AND type IN (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROC OrderDetail.WhereOrderHeaderID
GO

CREATE PROC OrderDetail.WhereOrderHeaderID
(
    @UsrID INT
    ,@OrderHeaderID INT
) AS
SELECT Item
    , Qty
    FROM OrderDetail
    WHERE OrderHeaderID = @OrderHeaderID

EXEC OrderHeader.[get] @UsrID,@OrderHeaderID
```

That is much easier to read, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: You did not answer the question asked by the user. While the SQL comments are nice, they are by far secondary to the core question.

Comment: what question, @JohnFarrar?  all I see is a request for a general review of the code given, I don't see any other question.